# Confusion about Crons

Tags: linux, unix, cron, aix

this is my first time writing script for cron job.

I wrote my code in shell, (which it works) and I'm trying to set it up for cron.
So here is my question. How do I set up the cron? Am I suppose to write 
`10 * * * * /home/workstation/deleter.sh` (I want it to run every 10min)
right underneath `#!/bin/sh`? How would I execute it? (deleter.sh has permission via chmod) 
man 1 crontab returns "No entry for crontab in section 1 of the manual"
I'm really lost and confused right now. If someone know how to set up cron please tell me!!

Thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/sh

counter=0
logloc=/home/ServerLogs
backup=/home/test
## Reads the location of the file systems that needs to be investigated from location.txt
## and save it into an array
while read -r line; do
   Unix_Array[${counter}]=$line;
   let counter=counter+1;
done < location.txt
## Reads Email recipients and save it into an array
More code continues from here......
```

Comment: You should do [some research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) yourself before asking.

Comment: well I did and it doesn't really say what to do. It skips the part where I can actually write code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup the cron, you can do one of two (main) things. The first would be to place the specified line in `/etc/crontab`. The second would be to run `crontab -e` and place the line in there. I would recommend to use `crontab -e` so the cron will execute as your own user account.

If the full path to the script is `/home/workstation/deleter.sh` and it *does* have execute-privileges, as you specified - your current line will have it execute 10-minutes past the hour, every hour. To get it to execute every 10 minutes, you'll have to use `*/10`, like this:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/workstation/deleter.sh
```

Comment: i tried crontab -e before it doesn't work         -ksh: crontab: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: @user1516649 Try using the full-path to the executable, such as `/usr/bin/crontab -e`. If this still says "not found", try locating it with `whereis crontab` or `which crontab`.

Comment: When I try whereis crontab I get this crontab: /usr/share/man/man1p/crontab.1p.bz2... i don't think this is the right file?

Comment: @user1516649 Is it possible that you don't have `crontab` installed? Check http://marguspala.com/bash-crontab-command-not-found/ to work towards that issue (if it exists). An alternative would be to just add the line to `/etc/crontab` and skip `crontab -e` (if time is important).

Answer (score 2):

The following will open your environment's text editor and load the crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Your crontab entry is mostly correct. In order for your script to run every ten minutes it should be changed to:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/workstation/deleter.sh
```

The entry you indicated would run the script at the 10th minute of every hour.

Answer (score 1):

this might help

http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

you need to get an entry into your crontab

Answer (score 1):

One of the best links I came across when I first learned about cron! Bookmark it

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/